# Epimorphisms have dense range in TopHausGrp?

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, ct.category-theory

Consider the category of Topological Groups with continuous homomorphisms.  Then a continuous homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ with dense range is an epimorphism.  Is the converse true?  If not, what about for locally compact groups?

Even for groups, without topology, this is not trivial-- Wikipedia points me to a simple proof given by Linderholm, "A Group Epimorphism is Surjective", The American Mathematical Monthly Vol. 77, No. 2 (Feb., 1970), pp. 176-177 see http://www.jstor.org/pss/2317336  It is far from obvious to me that this argument extends to the topological case (but perhaps it does).

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, I really was to ask about *Hausdorff* topologies.

Comment: There is rarely need to use abbreviations in MO questions (and, in your title, calling maps with dense image *surjective* is strange!)

Comment: I don't think the abbreviations hinder one's ability to read the question, myself. Though I agree that the way the title is worded is momentarily confusing...

Comment: I replaced the abbreviations - the meaning of 'cts' may not leap out at someone whose first language is not English, and 'homo' is a particularly inelegant abbreviation IMHO.

Comment: It's not true that a continuous homomorphism with dense range are epimorphisms, unless you work in the category of Hausdorff topological groups.  This is just because you can give any group the indiscrete topology, and in that context all maps have dense image.  Alternatively, you can consider the inclusion $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$, which equalises the projection and the zero map to the non-Hausdorff group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Apologies if my abbreviations annoyed anyone.  @Neil: Yes, good point!  This shows how little I think about non-Hausdorff things...

Comment: Mariano is right. I would even say that a mathematical text should never contain any abbreviation. This rule has been observed, I think, by the best authors: Bourbaki (also in English) , Grothendieck, Serre , Cartan and his seminarists,...

Comment: Georges: so I guess you prefer les groupes liminaires to CCR groups? (Pedersen has an amusing swipe at the over-use of acronyms)

Comment: See also SIN-groups, FC-groups, t-structures... 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google, MathSciNet and some ferreting lead me to

> MR1235755 (94m:22003)
>   Uspenskiĭ, Vladimir(D-MNCH)
>   The solution of the epimorphism problem for Hausdorff topological groups.
>   Sem. Sophus Lie 3 (1993), no. 1, 69–70.

where the review indicates that the answer is negative in general, but positive for locally compact groups; this latter case was apparently treated in

> MR0492044 (58 #11204)
>   Nummela, Eric C.
>   On epimorphisms of topological groups.
>   [Gen. Topology Appl. 9 (1978), no. 2, 155–167.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0016-660X%2878%2990060-0)

The case of compact groups had been done earlier by Poguntke:

> MR0263978 (41 #8577)
>   Poguntke, Detlev
>   Epimorphisms of compact groups are onto.
>   Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 26 1970 503–504.

and this apparently inspired the authors of the following paper

> MR1338245 (96c:46054)
>   Hofmann, K. H.(D-DARM); Neeb, K.-H.(D-ERL-MI)
>   Epimorphisms of $C^∗$-algebras are surjective.
>   Arch. Math. (Basel) 65 (1995), no. 2, 134–137.

Comment: It's interesting that the answer is "yes" for Hausdorff topological spaces, and "yes" for groups, but "no" for Hausdorff topological groups.

Comment: Many thanks.  I guess I really should have been able to find the Nummela paper myself, given its title!

Comment: I should add that the epimorphism of Hausdorff topological groups with non-dense image is actually between **Polish groups**. Namely, the inclusion of the stabilizer of a point in the group of self-homeomorphisms of the circle (or the Hilbert cube).

Comment: Link to Upenskii's paper: http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jlt/jlt03/USPENSPL.PDF