# Mono- and epi-morphisms for C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, ct.category-theory

This question is motivated by Yemon Choi's answer here: [Epimorphisms have dense range in TopHausGrp?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56453/epimorphisms-have-dense-range-in-tophausgrp/56459#56459)

It's well-known that the category of *unital* commutative C*-algebras and $*$-homomorphisms is dual to the category of compact Hausdorff spaces and continuous maps.  One finds that for all C*-algebras (with $*$-homomorphisms as morphisms) that monomorphisms are just injective maps, and epimorphisms are surjections (the latter point is non-trivial-- see the final paper which Yemon suggests in the link above).

Suppose instead we look at *locally* compact Hausdorff spaces, with continuous maps as morphisms.  Then dually, we get all commutative C*-algebras, but now the notion of a $*$-homomorphism is too restrictive (it corresponds to proper continuous maps).  Instead we say that a morphism between C*-algebras $A$ and $B$ is a non-degenerate $*$-homomorphism $A\rightarrow M(B)$ form $A$ to the multiplier algebra of $B$.  Such a map extends uniquely to a strictly continuous $*$-homomoprhisms $M(A)\rightarrow M(B)$, and so we can compose such maps.  Hence we get a category.  A little checking shows that the full subcategory of commutative C*-algebras, with these morphisms, is now dual to the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces with continuous maps.  (I think Woronowicz was the first person to articulate this view).

> For C*-algebras, with morphisms as arrows, what are epimorphisms and monomorphisms?

Restricting to the commutative case, we can instead look at locally compact Hausdorff spaces, and reverse the arrows.  So working through, a monomorphism remains just an injective map; but I see no simple description of epimorphisms (at the level of algebras-- for spaces, it's just injective continuous maps).

*Edit:* Maybe this notion of "non-degenerate" is confusing.  If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map between locally compact Hausdorff spaces, then we define $f_*:C_0(Y)\rightarrow C^b(X); a \mapsto a\circ f$.  Notice that we really do need the codomain to be all bounded continuous functions-- but that's okay, as $C^b(X)$ is just the multiplier algebra of $C_0(X)$, and $f_*$ turns out to be non-degenerate.  Conversely, every non-degenerate $*$-homomorphism $C_0(Y)\rightarrow C^b(X)$ arises in this way (but a general $*$-homomorphism $C_0(Y)\rightarrow C^b(X)$ can be much more complicated).

Comment: In the nonunital case, we have to restrict continuous maps between locally compact Hausdorff spaces to only the proper ones. To get a categorical duality, I think we also have to restrict *-homomorphisms between (nonunital) C*-algebras to nondegenerate ones, i.e. those $f \colon A \to B$ for which $\{f(a)b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$ is dense in $B$. So we really want to know what epimorphisms in this category are, which should hopefully make the question easier.

Comment: Chris, I may be missing something, but isn't the whole point of Matthew's question that he *doesn't* want to restrict only to proper continuous maps between LCH spaces, but instead consider all continuous maps between such?

Comment: Oh, I see. So the question is equivalent to what the monomorphisms in the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces with continuous maps are?

Comment: Yes, exactly-- if you restrict to commutative C*-algebras, then you can equivalently ask: "What are monomorphisms and epimorphisms in the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces with continuous maps as morphisms?"

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why $*$-homomorphisms would be too restrictive a choice, but taking those as morphisms between C*-algebras as objects, the epimorphisms are precisely the surjective $*$-homomorphisms. This is proposition 2 in G. A. Reid's "Epimorphisms and surjectivity", Inventiones Mathematicae 9:295-307, 1970. ([EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/142015))

Comment: I wasn't aware of the paper; it looks interesting. (It seems not to have been noticed or cited by the authors of the paper I mentioned in the answer Matthew links to -- a case of reinventing the wheel?)

Comment: Yes, so this gives a nice answer to the question with *-homomorphisms-- as Yemon says, this paper also pre-dates the reference Yemon found).  But, I'll leave this open, as I think this doesn't answer my actual question.

Comment: Btw, I regard `$*$`-homomorphisms as "too restrictive" by comparison with the commutative case-- `$*$`-homomorphisms $C_0(X)$ to $C_0(Y)$ only correspond to "proper" (inverse image of compact is compact) continuous maps $X\rightarrow Y$.  If you want all continuous maps, then you need this more general notion of morphism.

Comment: In fact, the algebra homomorphisms seem to be too restrictive when one deals with tensor products (for instance Haagerup tensor product). The point is that sometimes seems more natural to consider B as an A-bimodule, and then to obtain the morphism of category of Hilbert C*-modules over A into the one over B. But then is seems more natural to consider the maps A$\to$End<sub>B</sub>B = M(B). This picture has very nice analogies in the operator algebra theory.